# Can I compare model output from GARCH and EGARCH when the EGARCH is log conditional variance?

Tags: r, garch, logarithm

I have used the `rugarch` package in R to construct a `sGARCH` and an `eGARCH` model, but have come to doubt then assessing my the models. Does the `eGARCH` function in `rugarch` transform the log conditional variance into normal variance, or do I have to transform the models forecasted sigmas by hand?

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the fitted sigmas are estimates of the actual conditional standard deviations, not their logarithms. If you cannot find this information in the help files, simulate a time series by a known data generating process. Estimate the model and obtain the fitted sigmas. See if they are closer to the actual ones or to their logarithms. When I tried this (see the code below), I got fitted sigmas close to the true conditional standard deviations, not their logarithms.

```r
library(rugarch)
set.seed(1); x=rnorm(1e3)   # true conditional standard deviation = 1 at all times
uspec=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="eGARCH"))
ufit=ugarchfit(spec=uspec,data=x)
sigmahat=sigma(ufit)
print(head(sigmahat))
```

(It would be more elegant to use `ugarchpath` for simulating an actual EGARCH series, but I just used an i.i.d. one.)